# How to import variables from other .ipynb on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've seen a lot of other questions here about this topic however none have helped. I am coding on Jupyter Notebook using Python 3, to organize my code I am trying to use 2 different modules for my program. Thus I have 1 module called let's for simplicity call it **abc.ipynb** and now created a different module called for simplicity **edf.ipynb** (Both on Jupyter Notebook)

At first i wasn't able to import abc to edf but after importing the **import_ipynb** package and fixing the PYTHONPATH it worked.

However, now I just want to import variables from abc to edf, I am trying:

1. from abc import x
2. import abc        print(abc.x)
3. I even tried calling a function

All give 1 of below errors:

1. cannot import name 'x' from 'abc'
2. module 'abc' has no attribute 'function'

Any advice? I already created an **init**.py in my folder however I think it is of no use since I am working with .ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the name of the file other than "abc". Python already has a module called `abc`

Comment: Abc is just a fake name I am using to denote any module. My actual model is called CV_Screening_Random_Forest

Comment: Ah.. never mind then. you should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Fixed it :) any help?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing and found a workaround by creating a function in a separate functions.py file that returns the variable I wanted to pass between files

```
from functions.py import get_variable
desired_variable = get_variable()
```